# How to pass jquery variables to another php file

Tags: php, jquery

I have the code below for Java Script on getwifi1.php

```
$(function(){
 $('#wifi-avail').on('click', 'td', function(){
var txt;
var user;
var pass = prompt("Please enter your password:", "");
if (pass == null || pass == "") {
 txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
}
    user = $(this).html();
    $.post(
        "newone.php",
        {
        "username":user, 
        "password":pass
        }
    )
    alert(user);
    alert(pass);
}); //end inner function
}); //end outer function
```

I want to transfer the value of user and pass to another php file named newone.php in which I have written this code

```
<?php
$name1 = $_POST['username'];
$name2 = $_POST['password'];
echo $name1;
echo $name2;
?>
```

but the $name1 and $name2 seems to be empty always. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone correct my method or write me another code to transfer these two variables from getwifi1.php to newone.php. I have search ajax method which I applied like this but it didn't seem to work either

```
$.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "newone.php",
        data: {username:user, password:pass}
    })
```

ThankYou

Comment: How do you know `$name1` and `$name2` are empty?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Have you inspected your browser's developer console to see whether the data is passed to the backend properly?

Comment: Your code should work. In the php try var_dump($_POST) to see if you have the variables. Also, in JS, before the ajax call console.log the user and pass to make sure they have info.

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> Type: An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of
>   jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

<strike>I'm not sure, but I think you have to change 'method' to 'type' in your Ajax call.</strike>
My bad, this is not true and necessary.

This script should be working (and alert any error messages from your newone.php):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'newone.php',
    data: { 
        username: user, 
        password: password
    },
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/